# Round down operation result in IEEE 754

Tags: floating-point, rounding, ieee-754

For operations using single precision values in IEEE 754 (float, 32bit), is there a way to somehow condition the two operands to ensure that the operation result is rounded down, when an exact result is not possible? In other words, how can I force round to -Inf?

Example:

- Typical result (using 'round to nearest'): `1.0f / 3.0f = 0.3333333432674407958984375f`
- Expected result (using 'round down'): `1.0f / 3.0f = 0.333333313465118408203125f`

As additional info, I would be doing this in C99, and (unfortunatly) it's not possible to configure the FPU.

Comment: Re “in C99, and (unfortunatly) it's not possible to configure the FPU”: Why do you say that? C 1999 specifies facilities for this in clause 7.6, with the `<fenv.h>` header.

Answer (score 2):

Both C 1999 and the current C standard specify facilities for setting the floating-point rounding mode. However, not all C implementations support them. In implementations that do, the following code will save the previous rounding mode, perform operations with round-to-negative-infinity, and restore the previous rounding mode:

```
//  Declare identifiers for accessing floating-point environment.
#include <fenv.h>


void foo(void *data)
{
    //  Inform compiler this code accesses the floating-point environment.
    #pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON

    //  Save caller's rounding mode.
    int PreviousRoundingMode = fegetround();

    //  Set desired rounding mode.
    if (fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD) != 0)
    {
        //  fesetround failed.  Handle error.
    }

    //  Insert here code to perform desired operations.

    //  Restore previous rounding mode.
    fesetround(PreviousRoundingMode);
}
}
```

Note that basic operations, such as `+`, `*`, `-`, `/`, and `fma` can be expected to conform to the rounding mode, but math library functions such as `sin` or `log` might not.